# Swagger codegen .swagger-codegen-ignore not working

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I have been struggling with this one for a few days. Trying to ensure that my controller logic doesn't get overwritten. Generating python-flask server stubs.

swagger-codegen version: 2.2.3

.swagger-codegen-ignore contents

```
# Swagger Codegen Ignore
unity_controller.py
```

swagger-codegen generate -i ../tmp/swagger.yml -l python-flask -o ./

```
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from ../tmp/swagger.yml
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /Users/nctiggy/Syncplicity/DropBox/unity-sbux-hackathon/./swagger_server/models/unity_detail.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /Users/nctiggy/Syncplicity/DropBox/unity-sbux-hackathon/./swagger_server/models/unity_summary.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.AbstractGenerator - writing file /Users/nctiggy/Syncplicity/DropBox/unity-sbux-hackathon/./swagger_server/controllers/unity_controller.py
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator - File exists. Skipped overwriting /Users/nctiggy/Syncplicity/DropBox/unity-sbux-hackathon/./swagger_server/test/test_unity_controller.py
```

I excluded the rest of the files that are being written as I am not concerned with those. It looks like the ignore works for the one test file which is using a DefaultGenerator versus the AbstractGenerator.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have to specify that it is multi directories deep.

Specifying

```
#Swagger Codegen Ignore
swagger_server/controllers/unity_controller.py
```

fixed the issue.

I could also specify using wildcards if I wanted it to be less specific. Not the behavior I was expecting but it will do.